# Rewards credit card for large repeating purchases in Australia

Tags: credit-card, australia, reward-program

I have no revolving credit card debt: I pay it off every month. I also have a significant throughput of charging/paying off, including a large repeating medical cost that will be at least $3000 every 8 weeks. (Or about $20,000 / year). I am trying to find a good (or the best) **cash-back rewards credit card in Australia** to help me minimize the pain in my situation. Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

P.S. Don't worry, I will continue to pay it off in full every month.

Comment: Have you asked the medical biller if they would consider a discount for a cash payment? In the US, such a bill would be able to get about 2%. A promt check might get you better than that.

Comment: Good thought. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://australia.creditcards.com/

I have used the US version to research what kind of card I should apply for and turns out they have an Australia site.